# Convert mysql query into codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

How to convert this query to codeingniter framework:

```
SELECT sname FROM alumni WHERE email IN (SELECT * FROM alumni_user WHERE uname = '')
```

Comment: Short answer hire a developer. But more generally SO is not the place that you give a request and a team of developers 'solves' your problem. Try something by yourself, show us your code, present us any issues or frustrating points and then we can help you.

Comment: Read the doc : http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/examples.html

Comment: the answer by Narendra uses codeigniter active record -- must read: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this one..

```
$this->db->select('*');

$this->db->from('alumni_user');

$this->db->where('uname','');

$result = $this->db->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$q = $this->db->query("SELECT sname FROM alumni WHERE email IN (SELECT * FROM alumni_user WHERE uname = '')");

if($q->num_rows() > 0)
{
    $data = $q->result_array();
    print_r($data);
}
else
{
    echo '';
}
```